# Show that if $R$ is a strict partial order on $X$, and $R$ is not linear, then there exists a strict partial order $R'$ and $R' \supsetneqq R$.

Tags: proof-writing, relations, equivalence-relations

Question: Show that if $R$ is a strict partial order on $X$, and $R$ is not linear, then there exists a strict partial order $R'$ and $R' \supsetneqq R$.

My attempt: By definition 6.23,6.3.1, and 6.3.2ii,

R is irreflexive if $(\forall x \in S[(x,x) \notin R)$

R is antisymmetric if $(\forall x,y \in S)((x,y) \in R \land (y,x) \in R] \rightarrow (x=y)]$

R is transitive if $( \forall x,y,z \in S)[(x,y) \in R \land (y,z) \in R \rightarrow (x,z) \in R)]$

Furthermore, by Definition 6.3.2iii, a linear order occurs if $R$ is a strict partial order and every two elements of $S$ are comparable.

Suppose $R$ isn't a linear order. Then $R$ isn't a strict partial order, and there is at least one pair of elements that aren't comparable. Also, $R'$ means that it's reflexive, symmetric, and not transitive.

Here's my question...since I've already given the definition of linear and strict partial order, what would be a good example to show that $R' \supsetneqq R$. Maybe there's a unique element that exists in $R'$, but not in $R$. What if I let $R =$ all 26 letters of the alphabet and $R' =$ all 26 letters of the alphabet and numbers?

I tried to let $R=1,2,3$ and $R'=3,4,5$ but that didn't work since all of the same elements must be in $R$ and $R'$ meaning there must be $R =1,2,3$ and $R' = 1,2,3$ . However there is nothing unique. Sure all of the elements are in $R$ and $R'$, but where is the uniqueness in $R'$? So I thought about the alphabets and numbers which kind of work but seem childish.

What if I let the example be that $R = 1,2,3$ and $R' = 1,2,3,4$? There are elements in common in $R$ and $R'$ which is $1,2,3$, but $R'$ only has the number 4. As a result $R' \supsetneqq R$. What do you guys think? Any improvements? hints?

Comment: (1) The negation of antisymmetric is not symmetric; (2) your negation of "not linear order" is wrong.

Comment: so how do I correct that? we know that a linear order occurs if R is a strict partial order and every two elements of S are comparable.
Won't not linear order mean that R isn't a strict partial order? A strict partial order is irreflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive. What the heck would not strict partial order be if the negation of antisymmetric isn't symmetric?

Comment: I don't like your definition of *strict partial order*.  If you look at the hypothesis to the second part of the definition ($(x,y) \in R, \ (y,x) \in R$), that is *never satisfied* if the first part *irreflexive* is already there.  Thus antisymmetry is satisfied vacuously, so doesn't need to be stated?

Comment: @EnjoysMath I've provided the strict partial order definition exactly as the textbook tells me. D:

Comment: @usukidoll do you see what I mean though?  A good definition won't have blatant redundancies which this one has.  How can the *antisymmetry* filter ever find anything in $R$ after the *irreflexive* filter is applied?

Comment: A relation R on a set S is an order relation and (S,R) is an ordered set if R is antisymmetric and transitive. An order relation R is a 
1. partial order if it's also reflexive
2. strict partial order if it's also irreflexive 
 3. linear order if it's a strict partial order and every two elements of S are comparable...
[wouldn't it be that for not a linear order that there isn't a strict partial order and there is at least one pair of elements that's not comparable?]

Comment: Made some edits to my answer.  See if it makes sense now.

Comment: @EnjoysMath: irreflexive and antisymmetric are *not* redundant. The combination tells us that $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ cannot both be in $R$. However, irreflexive and transitive render antisymmetric unnecessary.

Comment: @robjohn cool, thanks.  I knew *something* was going on there.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R$ be a strict partial order on $S. \ $ For ex. $R = \{(x,y)\}, \ $ where $x \neq y$ are from $S$, is a strict partial order.  Let $R' = \{(y,x)\}$.  Clearly that is another *SPO*, and disjoint from $R$.  How did we come about it?  Well, we reversed the relation i.e. if $(x,y) \in R$, then put $(y, x) \in R'$.  This might work in the general case.  Let's check.

Let $R$ be an SPO.  Let $R' = R \text{ with relationships reversed}. \ $ Then Clearly $R'$ is irreflexive, and transitive (check this one).  And the definition to antisymmetry is the same wth $x,y$ reversed (*as text in the definition!!!*), so is also satisfied.  And $R \cap R' = \varnothing$ or else $(x,y) \in R \cap R' \implies (y,x) \in R'$ and by transitivity $(x,x) \in R'$ which violates irreflexivity.  Thus we've done way better than $R' \supsetneq R$.

That proves what you set out to.

Comment: $R'$ is irreflexive $(\forall x \in S[(x,x) \notin R')$...

$R'$ is antisymmetric $(\forall y,x \in S)((y,x) \in R' \land (x,y) \in R'] \rightarrow (y=x)]$

Comment: $R'$ is transitive if $( \forall y,x,z \in S)[(y,x) \in R' \land (x,z) \in R' \rightarrow (y,z) \in R')]$

Comment: @usukidoll I don't get what your comments are asking.

Comment: I'm trying to apply the definition of the strict partial order for $R'$. And how the heck is $R'$ transitive when the original definition has three elements $x,y$ and $z$?

Comment: I can see that $R'$ is irreflexive since $(\forall x \in S)((x,x) \notin R')$ and we're just dealing with one element.